# Swift error: Cannot call value of non-function type ‘UInt32'

Tags: swift, function

I have created a character function using Swift. 
From the tutorial I am following it works okay, however in my case but the compiler display error message.
Here is the code:

```
import Foundation

class Enemy: Character {

  var loot: [String] {
    return ["Rusty Dagger","Blue Tunic"]
  }

  var type: String {
    return "Grunt"
  }

  func dropLoot() -> String? {

    if !isAlive {
        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(<#T##UInt32#>(loot.count))) // compile error
        return loot[rand]
    }

    return nil
  }
}
```

I get the following compile error

> Cannot call value of non-function type ‘UInt32'

Why?

Screenshot:

[image]

Could someone please enlighten me? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Just replace the "UInt32" placeholder text by a real text ...

Comment: @Sulthan: Your edit hid the actual problem :)

Comment: @MartinR You are right, I was looking at the screenshot and didn't notice the slightly different color on `UInt32`.